# WHERE clause with condition

Tags: sql

Ok here is the issue,

```
   SELECT CTE.TECHNICIANID, SUM(TLEVEL) AS TLEVEL, TECH.PASSEDDRUGTEST, TECH.PASSEDBACKGROUNGCHECK, TECH.FIRSTNAME, TECH.LASTNAME, 
        CM.CITYID, CM.ADDRESS, CM.EMAIL, CM.PHONENUMBER, CM.ZIPCODE, CNTRY.COUNTRYNAME, SM.STATENAME,
         CM.LATITUDE, CM.LONGITUDE FROM CTE
        INNER JOIN TECHNICIAN TECH ON CTE.TECHNICIANID = TECH.TECHNICIANID 
        INNER JOIN SERVICEORDER SO ON SO.SERVICEORDERID = @SERVICEORDERID
        INNER JOIN CONTRACT CONT ON SO.CONTRACTID = CONT.CONTRACTID
        INNER JOIN CONTACTMASTER CM ON CM.CONTACTID = TECH.CONTACTID
        INNER JOIN COUNTRYMASTER CNTRY ON CM.COUNTRYID = CNTRY.COUNTRYID
        INNER JOIN STATEMASTER SM ON SM.STATEID = CM.STATEID
        --WHERE CONT.DRUGSCREENINGREQUIRED = CASE CONT.DRUGSCREENINGREQUIRED  WHEN 'TRUE' THEN TECH.PASSEDDRUGTEST END AND
        --CONT.BACKGROUNDCHECKREQUIRED = CASE CONT.BACKGROUNDCHECKREQUIRED WHEN 'TRUE' THEN TECH.PASSEDBACKGROUNGCHECK END
        GROUP BY CTE.TECHNICIANID, TECH.PASSEDDRUGTEST, TECH.PASSEDBACKGROUNGCHECK,CM.LATITUDE, TECH.FIRSTNAME, TECH.LASTNAME, 
        CM.CITYID, CM.ADDRESS, CM.EMAIL, CM.PHONENUMBER, CM.ZIPCODE, CNTRY.COUNTRYNAME, SM.STATENAME, CM.LONGITUDE ORDER BY TLEVEL DESC
```

look at the commented part in the query with where clause, what I want there is when `drugscreening` required is `true` I want all records with `passeddrugtest` as `true` in else case I do not want to apply any condition

Edit: When `CONT.DRUGSCREENINGREQUIRED` and `CONT.BACKGROUNDCHECKREQUIRED` is true then only I want to filter the records with `TECH.PASSEDDRUGTEST` and `TECH.PASSEDBACKGROUNGCHECK`. If they are not true I want all records no matter whether `TECH.PASSEDDRUGTEST` and `TECH.PASSEDBACKGROUNGCHECK` is true or false.

Comment: Don't forget to tag your RDBMS. This can help people help you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I've misunderstood the question, but could you not just do this?

```
WHERE CONT.DRUGSCREENINGREQUIRED = 'FALSE' OR CONT.DRUGSCREENINGREQUIRED = 'TRUE' AND TECH.PASSEDDRUGTEST = 'TRUE'
```

Answer (score 0):

If those flags are independent (contrary to the question, but it seems to me that it should be so), you might retrieve records where check is not required or the check is passed, in short like this:

```
WHERE (CONT.DRUGSCREENINGREQUIRED = 'FALSE' OR TECH.PASSEDDRUGTEST = 'TRUE')
  AND (CONT.BACKGROUNDCHECKREQUIRED = 'FALSE' OR TECH.PASSEDBACKGROUNGCHECK = 'TRUE')
```

If you really want to check `passed` status if both flags are raised, then you might use this patern:

```
WHERE (    CONT.DRUGSCREENINGREQUIRED = 'FALSE' 
        OR CONT.BACKGROUNDCHECKREQUIRED = 'FALSE'
        OR (     TECH.PASSEDDRUGTEST = 'TRUE' 
             AND TECH.PASSEDBACKGROUNGCHECK = 'TRUE'
           )
      )
```